# Relation between LCM and GCD

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I am trying to prove relation between G.C.D and L.C.M for three integers.
Is the following relation even true. If yes, then I need hints please.
let a, b and c be any integers then,

$$lcm(a,gcd(b,c))=gcd(lcm(a,b),lcm(a,c))$$
Or in notations,
$$[a,(b,c)]=([a,b],[a,c])$$

Comment: Have you tried some examples?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes, this holds in examples. But I need to prove it generally.

Comment: We can write $a = \prod_{i=1}^\infty p_i^{k_i}$ (where an infinite number of $k_i$ are zero and only a finite number of them aren't zero) and $b = \prod_{i=1}^\infty p_i^{m_i}$ then $\gcd(a,b) = \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} p_i^{\min(k_i,m_i)}$ and $lcm(a,b) = \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} p_i^{max(k_i, m_i)}$.  If you use that this becomes very easy.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Try using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, but write with all prime numbers (some with power $0$) rather than just the ones in the factorization.

Then if you look at each prime number, you will find the problem becomes essentially $max(A, min(B,C))=min(max(A,B), max(A,C))$ which I will leave you to prove.

Comment: Thankyou @cr001 I will try this approach.